# ExtenderControlBase.cs not found when I am using the calendarExtender Ajax Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I got this error when I am trying to add an Ajax calendar.  I have downloaded the Ajax Control Toolkit from the CodePlex (I tried the new release (dec 2013 and the previous one).  I added a new tab in the ToolBox called Ajax Control Toolkit and Choose Items to add the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file to it.
When I compiled I notice a new Bin folder in my Solution Explorer.  It contains two files AjaxControlToolkit.dll and the AjaxControlToolKit.pdb.

I put this in my Web.config:

```
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp"
           namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
           assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="label"> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate1" runat="server" Text="Choose a date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" />
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarDate1" TargetControlID="txtDate1" 
           Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using a master page and a content place holder.  I am using C# VS Express 2013.  Also where do we get a free calendar.png image to add to the calendar box ?

I saw it might be related with the Microsoft Ajax Minifier (http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxMin/) but this command is just working in a project.  I am in a Web Site not in a Project.  Here is the error "The current environment doesn't have a solution open" when I ran the following command "Install-Package AjaxMin" at the Package Manager Console.

Comment: more info   Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/SP_Admin/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/WebSites/TP2/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\TP2\bin
Calling assembly : AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e.
===

Comment: LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\TP2\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy the file AjaxMin.dll from where I extracted the AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET40.zip, to my project's bin folder.   Also I removed the AjaxControlToolKit.pdb from the Bin folder.